# How to customize link toolbar on right clicking text in pdftron reactjs

Tags: reactjs, text, hyperlink, modal-dialog, pdftron

**Product**: webviewer

**Product Version**:  “^7.3.3”,

*Please give a brief summary of your issue*:
I want to create a custom modal while selecting text and create it a link. Please share how to customize link toolbar and create a custom modal on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like you already asked this question on our form here https://community.pdftron.com/t/how-to-customize-link-toolbar-on-right-clicking-text-in-pdftron-reactjs/7190